# Does <li> always need to be nested between <ul> and <ol>? not <nav>

Tags: html

I know this question has been asked in various ways specifically with 'nav'

But I keep coming across web pages where 'li' is a child of 'section' or 'article' with no preceding 'ul or 'ol' parent elements. This is usually done in paragraphs. Is this a "correct" method? If so what other elements is it acceptable to omit the 'ol' and 'ul'.

'section'
'li'
lorem epsom carpe julgulerum
'/li'

( I know "correct" can be debatable especially when taking screen readers into account)

Thank you.

Comment: `The HTML <li> element is used to represent an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (<ol>), an unordered list (<ul>), or a menu (<menu>).` [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

Comment: oh yes you are correct, I have changed the question. I did mean child of an element other than ul or ol

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Mozilla Developer Network page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li):

> The HTML `<li>` element is used to represent an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (`<ol>`), an unordered list (`<ul>`), or a menu (`<menu>`).

So yes, you need to nest any `<li>` element inside a list or menu. However a `<li>` element may contain nearly every other element inside. And also yes, an `<article>` or a `<section>` may be contained inside a `<li>`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's quite as cut and dried as MDN make out. According to the [WHATWG living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element):

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>
> Inside ol elements.
>
> Inside ul elements.
>
> Inside menu elements.

But then later on it states:

> The li element represents a list item. If its parent element is an ol,
>   ul, or menu element, then the element is an item of the parent
>   element's list, as defined for those elements. **Otherwise**, the list
>   item has no defined list-related relationship to any other li element.

Which seems to suggest it would be legitimate to have an li not contained in one of these elements.

Looking at the user agent style sheet in Chrome it seems that all the "list styling" is contained in the parent element:

```
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
```

and an `li` is simply an item with a `display:list-item` component:

```
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
```

So it would seem to be legitimate to use a `li` outside of a list if you require an item with a display of `list-item`. How useful this would be outside of a list is open to debate.

---

Your other question:

> 'li' is a parent of 'section' or 'article'. Is this "correct"?

Yes an `<li>` can contain any other HTML. Just in the same way as any container can.

Comment: Just because the `<li>` has no relationship to other `<li>` elements there is no reason to ignore the “in which this element *can* be used”. This is very explicit to allow list elements only inside the mentioned three elements.

Comment: It's not explicit, it states in several places that a li element can or cannot be contained inside a ul/ol. The standard is a little confusingly worded but how else do you read *if the element is not a child of an ul or menu element*. This seems clear that a li does not need to be a child of ul or ol. MDN don't make the standards, W3C do

Comment: As you can read: “if the element is not a child of an ul or menu element”. There is nothing about an `ol`. So there is nowhere anything described about that `li` is allowed to be outside of `ul`, `ol` or `menu`.

Comment: Ok what about *If its parent element is an **ol, ul, or menu** element, then the element is an item of the parent element's list, as defined for those elements. **Otherwise**, the list item has no defined list-related relationship to any other li element.*?

Comment: That’s a declaration on how to behave with list elements outside the allowed elements. There is exactly written (as you already mentioned in your first quote) that it can be used in three contexts. Nowhere else. At least in my opinion and how I understand the standard.

Comment: *At least in my opinion and how I understand the standard.* exactly. It's not as *cut and dried as MDN make it appear*. The standard contains wiggle room and how Chrome actually behaves backs this up

Comment: Sorry, I DID mean li  child of section or article. I agree I don't think it is so cut and dry.

Comment: The WHATWG (not W3C, although this part is common for both of them) standard you cited has requirements for browsers as well as for authors. The "Contexts in which this element can be used" part is for authors who want to produce conforming documents. The "Otherwise" is for browsers that have to deal with _any_ HTML documents, including non-conforming: while having a `li` element outside the list container is *not legitimate,* browsers still have to parse and display such erroneous documents in a predictable way. It doesn't mean that the standard endorses such usage.

Answer (score 1):

The pages where `li` elements are nested directly in the `section`, `article`, or even `nav` elements clearly have incorrect markup. Both [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) and W3C (both [published](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) and [upcoming](https://w3c.github.io/html/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) version) standards state that `li` elements can be used only in context of the list elements (either `ol` or `ul`, the WHATWG standard also adds the `menu` option while the W3C standard doesn't have the `menu` element anymore). There are no other contexts where this element *can* be used.

However, since the HTML standard is designed to be error-resistant and resilient, it also has the rules for the browsers how to deal with the incorrect markup. This is why the definition of the `li` element has the (rather confusing) "otherwise" part, which describes what the browser should do if it encounters this element in the context where it *can not* be used. The page with such incorrect markup would still be displayable and mostly functional, but it would be not as accessible as the page with the correct markup (e.g. screenreaders would not be able to announce that there is the list and how many items it contains).

The `ul` and `ol` element containing `li` elements can be contained in any sectioning element (and in general, in any element whose [content model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-element-content-model) is ["Flow content"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2)). The `li` elements themselves technically can contain any "Flow content" (including sections and headings), but the W3C standard has the following note about it:

> While it is conforming to include heading elements (e.g., `h2`) and [Sectioning content](https://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#sectioning-content-2) inside li elements, it likely does not convey the semantics that the author intended. A heading starts a new section, so a heading in a list implicitly splits the list into spanning multiple sections. Sectioning content explicitly creates a new section and so splits the list into spanning multiple sections.

So if you have a list which has different sections/articles in its items, it's recommended to test this page for accessibility, to make sure that the way screenreaders present the information matches the author's intent.

Answer (score -1):

If you just use **li** tag without nesting inside **ul** tag or **ol** tag the rendered result will be an unordered list with bullet icons preceding **li** tag. This is not a standard format though it gives exact same output as you use it nested inside **ol** tag or **ul** tag.